# How to prove deg(f) = n iff the parity imbalance of f is non-zero?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

Not sure if the notation I'm using here is standard or not. I'm going over class notes and I'm stumped over an exercise given: Show that $deg(f) = n \iff PI(f) \neq 0$.

Here $f$ is a boolean function on $n$ variables. $PI(f) = \sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(0)} (-1)^{w(x)}$. $w(x)$ is the number of bits = 1 in the input $x$. $deg(f)$ is the minimum degree of any polynomial representation of $f$.

This implies a sufficient condition that $f$ is evasive is $PI(f) \neq 0$. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are asking about homework exercise, then this may not be the best place to ask your question. This site welcomes *research-level* questions. Please see the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on what is meant by "research-level" and for alternative places to ask your question. If after reading the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) you still feel that this is the appropriate venue for your question, perhaps you would like to rephrase it so that it doesn't sound like you are asking about a homework exercise.

Comment: This isn't really a homework exercise. It was from a graduate level course, I'm prepping for my oral exam, it was a lemma from class who's proof was ommited as (exercise). Sorry if this isn't the correct place for it.

Comment: If you substitute $\:\: n \: = \: \operatorname{deg}(f\hspace{.02 in})+1 \:\:$ into what you're supposed to show, you get $\: \operatorname{PI}(f\hspace{.02 in}) = 0 \:$.

Comment: I don’t think the exercise is correct. Let $f(x,y)=x+y$: then $\deg(f)=1<2=n$, but $\mathrm{PI}(f)=2\ne0$.

Comment: Lemma 4 in http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/497/05-evasive.pdf tells you that $\mathrm{PI}(f)\ne0$ is a *sufficient* condition for evasiveness, but not necessary.

Comment: Rewrite $PI(f) = - \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} [(-1)^{w(x)} \cdot f(x)]$ and show that this is 0 for every real function $f$ of degree less than $n$.

Comment: @Emil, you're right about it being sufficient, not necessary (it follows from the fact that $deg(f) \leq D(f)$ where $D(f)$ is minimum depth of any decision tree for $f$). I'm assuming here that $f:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, so the counter example doesn't work. Noam's trick solves this problem, thanks!

Comment: Also, how do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: The counterexample is $f\colon\{0,1\}^2\to\{0,1\}$ (the addition is in the $2$-element field, of course, i.e., parity). $f^{-1}(0)=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$, so $PI(f)=(-1)^0+(-1)^2=2$. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I see: when you say “polynomial representation” of a Boolean function, you mean a polynomial over the reals, not over the Boolean ring?

Comment: @OpenCovering, post your solution as an answer, and accept it.